# Orthogonal Projections: Prove that $\left\|P_1+P_2\right\|\leq\left\|P_1\right\|+\left\|P_2\right\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, projective-space

If $P_1$, $P_2$ are orthogonal projections (other than $0$) and $P_1P_2 = 0$, then show that $\left\|P_1+P_2\right\|\leq\left\|P_1\right\|+\left\|P_2\right\|$.

I hope you help me.

Comment: This holds in general for linear operators, are you sure you do not mean another inequality?

Comment: "Norm" = "a thing where that inequality holds" (and a couple of other minor things).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli "minor" :)

Comment: @s.harp but not unimportant.